# how to add custom url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

In my wordpress site url came the following format.

http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=23

But i want it will come

http://localhost/wordpress.contact.php

this format.

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings->Permalinks you can edit the structure of your URLs, but you won't be able to have just a dot between wordpress and the page name without using some .htaccess tricks. To have something like /post-name.php/ you would need:

```
/%postname%.php/
```

In the custom structure box on the settings page.